# Websphere EjbException Wrapping

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, transactions, websphere, websphere-7

Is there a way to change the default EJBException handling of Websphere 7 application servers?

We have an EJB which starts a new Transaction:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class SomeDaoBean implements SomeDaoLocal {


    @Override
    public void persistObject(SomeObject object) {
        ...
    }
}
```

when the transaction gets commited by the container and there's a rollback, we can't get the original cause. The EJB that calls persistObject does something like this:

```
try {
    someDao.persistObject(someObject);
} catch (final EJBException ejbE) {
    handleEjbException(someObject, ejbE);
}
```

When we try to handle and log the caught EJBException, the causes are all instances of EJBTransactionRolledBackException and Websphere logs the Original (e.g. java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) into SystemOut.log.

Is there a way to configure Websphere

- To not lose the original Exception over transaction boundaries
- To not log it into SystemOut.log

I know I could handle the JPA Excpetions by having an Interceptor and flush by myself but I don't like that solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to not lose the original exception without somehow managing the transaction yourself.

The EJB specification requires logging system exceptions, and there is no option in WebSphere Application Server to disable that logging.